# Connecting to Oracle Wallet from Cloud web application

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have recently started deploying my web applications into Google cloud platform. Fortunately, I've solved every annoying errors, exceptions, troubles on my own by researching in stack overflow and other platforms. My current deployed application establish the connection to my real oracle database which is located in Oracle Cloud Infrastructure. While running my web app in localhost, of course it connects because the config file points to wallet folder in my file system. But now in cloud, I don't know where to store my wallet to reference it from my hibernate config xml. And also I don't know if it's possible to reference somewhere other than filesystem, like https://blablafileupload.com/mywalletfolder.

I'm gonna provide my config file below. Can you help me if you know how to do it, and also where is the best place for storing such database wallets (I guess the storage in the location same as my deployment is good place, but I don't know how).

```
-<bean class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="myDataSource">

<property value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" name="driverClass"/>

<property value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@oraclesql_medium?TNS_ADMIN=/Users/user/Desktop/Fuad/Wallet_OracleSQL/" name="jdbcUrl"/>

<property value="TABLE" name="user"/>

<property value="********" name="password"/>

<!-- these are connection pool properties for C3P0 -->


<property value="5" name="minPoolSize"/>

<property value="20" name="maxPoolSize"/>

<property value="30000" name="maxIdleTime"/>

</bean>
```

As you can see on 3rd line, it refers to the wallet folder in my filesystem ( I want to store that somewhere and make xml refers to it on Internet.)